# How to check every row/column in a table and log all the errors found in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019-express

I need help on how to code this in SQL Server 2019 Express.

I have a flat file that I `BULK INSERT` into a temporary table. What I wanted to do is on how to log every verification/invalid data on each row/column to another table which is the `Error_Log_Table`.

For example:

```
  INSERT INTO dbo.FileTable (ID, ROWNUM, Data1, Data2, Data3)
      SELECT 
          ID, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Data1 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ROWNUM, 
          ROUND(CAST(Data1 AS DECIMAL) / 100, 2) AS Data1, Data2, Data3 
      FROM  
          #tmpBulkTable
```

Now, that's how I insert the bulk data to a temporary table. I have to check every column and row that it meets the data validation needed and have to log every error/mistake I see. Would you kindly suggest how to make this work.

Comment: Write a query that does the validating, would be where i'd start

Comment: You can use While loop or Cursor in this scenario if you are validation against a set of pre-defined functional rules.

Comment: @CaiusJard, the validation is if data1 is existing on data1_validation _table, mostly like that way.

Comment: Might need a bit more information to work with than what you've posted.. To understand your question from my perspective: Imagine you're a software developer at a new company, and your boss comes in and drops this spec on you on day 1: "validate all the info generated by Important Teams in the business, against The Rules and put a log in the Usual Place so we can see if anyone is doing work that breaks the rule". It doesn't define what makes an important team, what the information is, what the rules are, what the output looks like or where the usual place is. That is what you've asked here..

Comment: Show us some sample data and what you want to put in error log.